# как разблокировать windows с помощью python

Tags: python, windows, aiogram

Есть бот на aiogram, сделал там функцию блокировки компьютера, нужно теперь добавить функцию разблокировки компьютера, блокировка заменяет стандартное сочитание клавиш Win + L. Нужен код для разблокировки зная пароль, пробовал через PyAutoGui, но почему то не вводится пароль в поле для ввода. Может кто нибудь поможет?

Comment: не думаю что какая-та программа может разблокировать компьютер когда он заблокирован

Comment: как минимум, PyAutoGUI спокойно двигал курсор и нажимал на пробел, чтобы смахнуть вверх заставку экрана блокироки, единственное ему не удавалось взять в фокус поле ввода пароля и ввести сам пароль